# Any way to sort/group fields in the Insert a Field list?

Tags: sharepoint-server, infopath

[image: This list here.]

Any way to sort the fields? I'm creating a form with numerous fields; the list will be long, and I'd like to use a naming convention for related fields, to make it easier to see at a glance which fields "go together." But right now the fields are just listed in order of creation. So, if I forget to make field "C" until after I've already made field "M," then field "C" will be way down on the list and "out of order." Any solution?